# Cashier single charge with secure payment throws Stripe ApiErrorException

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, laravel-spark

I am using the newest Laravel Spark and Cashier. Currently, I am testing the secure payments which are working for subscriptions. However, when I perform a single charge (which worked for the older Spark version):

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::get('services.stripe.secret'));
$invoice_item = \Stripe\InvoiceItem::create([
  'customer' => $user->stripe_id,
  'amount' => $dollars_cents_with_tax,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'description' => $description
]);

$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create([
  'customer' => $user->stripe_id
]);

$charge = $invoice->pay();
```

However, it now throws an:

```
 Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException::factory vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php:38
```

and this message:

```
    Stripe\Exception\CardException
    This payment requires additional user action before it can be completed successfully. Payment can be completed using the PaymentIntent associated with the invoice. For more details see: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#requires-action
```

Interestingly, an email is still mailed with the confirmation button:

```
 "Extra confirmation is needed to process your payment. Please continue to the payment page by clicking on the button below."
```

And this button is functional, upon clicking on it the transaction is verified and the charge is completed.

Anyone an idea to catch this API error or solving the underlying issue?

Comment: You're running into https://support.stripe.com/questions/handling-recurring-payments-that-require-customer-action -- the error itself can be caught as a normal error and logged (or whatever your specific flow needs to do to make sure you're aware of it): https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling

Comment: thanks taintedzodiac. The problem is that the stripe code is heavily integrated with cashier and spark So I am wondering if it's a bug related to cashier. I can't find the place where to catch the subsequent API error and continue with business (after logging).